# Cannot click elements in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs that the user can click on, and then they expand to cover the screen. In doing so, they become fixed position.

Everything works exactly as expected in all browsers **except** for Safari. When on Safari, once the div is expanded, the user cannot click anything inside the div. I have buttons and links that would take the user to other pages or close the div, but it behaves as if the user never clicked anything.

Here is a link: https://toucan-sam.firebaseapp.com/

Any insight would be appreciated.

I've created a snippet below using what I believe to be the relevant code, but the snippet actually displays the intended behavior.

```js
let $body = $('body');
let $introduction = $('#introduction');
let $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
let griffen = {
  viewportHeight: $introduction.height(),
  viewportWidth: $introduction.width(),
  preset: false,
  extrasVisible: false,
  projectVisible: false,
  projectOpening: false,
  projectClosing: false,
  mobileSize: 900,
};

let openProject = (project) => {
  'use strict';
  let open = () => {
    let containerPosition = project.article.offset().top - window.scrollY;
    let containerWidth = project.article.width();
    let containerHeight = project.article.height();
    project.container.css({
      'height': containerHeight + 'px',
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': containerPosition + 'px',
      'width': containerWidth + 'px',
      'z-index': '100',
    });
    if (project.id === 'sdot') {
      project.heading.css({
        'background-position': 'center 25%',
      });
      project.header.animate({
        'padding-left': '0',
        'padding-top': '20%',
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      project.header.animate({
        'padding-left': '0',
      }, 1000);
    }
    project.container.animate({
      'height': '100vh',
      'top': '0',
      'width': '100%',
    }, 1000, () => {
      project.container.addClass('full');
      griffen.projectOpening = false;
    });
  };

  $body.addClass('stuck');
  $('html').addClass('stuck');
  project.tabButton.attr('aria-selected', 'true');
  project.content.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
  let verticalPosition = project.article.offset().top - (griffen.viewportHeight / 2) + (project.article.height() / 2);
  let diff = Math.round(verticalPosition) - window.scrollY;
  console.log(diff);
  if (Math.abs(diff) > 50) {
    let doneScrolling = false;
    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': verticalPosition
    }, 500, () => {
      if (!doneScrolling) {
        doneScrolling = true;
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          open();
        }, 500);
      }
    });
  } else {
    open();
  }

};

let closeProject = (project) => {
  'use strict';
  let close = () => {
    let containerPosition = project.article.offset().top - window.scrollY;
    let containerWidth = project.article.width();
    let containerHeight = project.article.height();

    project.container.removeClass('full');
    project.container.animate({
      'height': containerHeight + 'px',
      'top': containerPosition + 'px',
      'width': containerWidth + 'px',
    }, 1000, () => {
      project.container.css({
        'height': '',
        'position': '',
        'top': '',
        'width': '',
        'z-index': '',
      });
      $body.removeClass('stuck');
      $('html').removeClass('stuck');
      griffen.projectClosing = false;
      griffen.projectVisible = false;
    });

    if (project.id === 'sdot') {
      project.heading.css({
        'background-position': '',
      });
      if (griffen.viewportWidth >= griffen.mobileSize) {
        project.header.animate({
          'padding-left': '250px',
          'padding-top': '0',
        }, 1000, () => {
          project.header.css({
            'padding-left': '',
            'padding-top': '',
          });
        });
      } else {
        project.header.animate({
          'padding-left': '0',
          'padding-top': '0',
        }, 1000, () => {
          project.header.css({
            'padding-left': '',
            'padding-top': '',
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (griffen.viewportWidth >= griffen.mobileSize) {
        project.header.animate({
          'padding-left': '250px',
        }, 1000, () => {
          project.header.css({
            'padding-left': '',
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };

  if (project.container.scrollTop() !== 0) {
    project.container.animate({
      'scrollTop': 0,
    }, 500, () => {
      close();
    });
  } else {
    close();
  }
};

let toggleProject = (project) => {
  'use strict';
  if (griffen.projectVisible === false) {
    if (griffen.projectOpening === false && griffen.projectClosing === false) {
      griffen.projectOpening = true;
      griffen.projectVisible = true;
      openProject(project);
    }
  } else {
    if (griffen.projectOpening === false && griffen.projectClosing === false) {
      griffen.projectClosing = true;
      closeProject(project);
    }
  }
};


let inciteWater = {
  article: $('#incite-water'),
  container: $('#incite-water-container'),
  header: $('#incite-water-header'),
  heading: $('#incite-water-heading'),
  content: $('#incite-water-content'),
  tabButton: $('#incite-water-button'),
  id: 'incitewater',
};
console.log(inciteWater);
inciteWater.tabButton.click((e) => {
  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.project-link').attr('aria-selected', 'false');
  $('[role="tabpanel"]').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
  toggleProject(inciteWater);
});

let $closeInciteWater = $('#close-incite-water-button');
$closeInciteWater.click((e) => {
  'use strict';
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.project-link').attr('aria-selected', 'false');
  $('[role="tabpanel"]').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
  closeProject(inciteWater);
});
```

```css
#introduction,
#sidebar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.project,
.project-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff
}

section>header {
  text-align: center
}

section p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 1em 0
}

.project-date,
.project-header {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.image {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center
}

.icon,
.project-header {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box
}

.project-content-title,
.project-header h3 {
  font-family: "Krona One", "IBM Plex Sans", "Hiragino Maru Gothic ProN", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em
}

.project {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 40vh;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.project-container,
.project-container>header {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}

.project-container {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  right: 0
}

.project-container>header {
  overflow: hidden
}

.project-container.full .project-header,
.project-link {
  position: absolute
}

.project-container.full {
  /* overflow-x:hidden; */
  ;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.project-link {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}

.project-header {
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 60vh;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: .25s opacity, .25s visibility, .25s top;
  -o-transition: .25s opacity, .25s visibility, .25s top;
  transition: .25s opacity, .25s visibility, .25s top;
  width: 100%
}

#contact,
#contact-form {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal
}

.project-header h3 {
  text-align: center
}

.project-pre-title {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  position: relative
}

.project-pre-title::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -1em;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  width: 8em
}

.project-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 150;
}

.project-content-intro {
  margin-bottom: 2em
}

.project-content-title {
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.project-date {
  margin: .5em 0
}

.close-project-button-dang {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3em;
  top: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background-image: url(../icons/cancel.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s opacity;
  -o-transition: .5s opacity;
  transition: .5s opacity
}

#incite-water-heading {
  background-image: url(https://toucan-sam.firebaseapp.com/assets/images/water-drops.jpeg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="introduction">
  INTRODUCTION
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  SIDEBAR
</div>
<article class="project" id="incite-water">
  <div class="project-container" id="incite-water-container">
    <header id="incite-water-heading">
      <a href="#incite-water" tabindex="0" class="project-link" id="incite-water-button" role="tab" aria-controls="incite-water-content" data-project="inciteWater">
        <div class="project-header" id="incite-water-header">
          <h3>Incite Water</h3>
          <span class="project-pre-title">Web Design &amp; Development</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="project-content" tabindex="0" id="incite-water-content" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="incite-water-button">
      <div class="project-content-intro">
        <div class="project-content-title">Incite Water</div>
        <div class="project-date">October 2017 – March 2018</div>
      </div>
      <p>This year, for the <a href="https://foster.uw.edu/centers/buerk-ctr-entrepreneurship/entrepreneurship-competitions/eic/" target="_blank">Alaska Airlines Environmental Innovation Challenge</a>, I worked on a project called Incite Water. Our team
        was comprised of peers from various departments and the goal was to create a simple yet powerful interface that would encourage people to save water. We hoped to do this by demonstrating how much money people could personally save while mitigating
        the potential environmental impacts of wasting water.</p>
      <p>For this project, I worked as the sole web developer. I created the interface of the site as well as the background connections with our servers. In a small group, we programmed the “calculator” first using client-side JavaScript. I then implemented
        the calculation using Node.js to run server-side to protect some sensitive information from exposure and to allow for easier implementation with the Firebase platform used to host the project.</p>
      <p>My role went beyond web development and extended to providing direction for our technology-based decisions and assessing feasibility. I advised we use Google’s Firebase platform to take advantage the free low-traffic hosting and integration with
        various database structures and cloud computing functions that enabled the quick prototyping of the product.</p>
      <p>Though we chose to go with a high-fidelity prototype, it is still a prototype. We hoped that by presenting a more realized product to judges our vision would be more effectively conveyed. Because it is still an early prototype, we need to perform
        additional user research and usability testing to determine our next course of action. I anticipate further adjustments to our calculator as well as increased outreach and awareness campaigns to involve more members of the public.</p>
      <p><a href="https://incitewater.com/" target="_blank" class="button">Visit Incite Water</a></p>
      <a href="#" id="close-incite-water-button" class="close-project-button" data-project="inciteWater">← Return<span class="sr-only"> to the main page</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you apply `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` the div is not clickable any longer in Safari. Removing said styling solves this.